# Replacement rule only matches part of expression

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching

I have the result of a calculation (which is too long to mention here) and it gives

```
-I (t2 - t4) (((Hy vx^2 - Hx vx vy + vz (Hz vy - Hy vz)) Re[Ex] + 
   Hx vz^2 Re[Ey] - Ey vz^2 Re[Hx] + 
   vx (Hy vy Re[Ey] - Hz vz Re[Ey] + Ex vy Re[Hx]) + 
   vy (3 Hx vz Re[Ez] - 3 Ez vz Re[Hx]) + (-Ex vx^2 + Ex vz^2 + 
   vx (-Ey vy + 3 Ez vz)) Re[Hy] - Ex vy vz Re[Hz] + 
   vx (-3 Hy vz Re[Ez] + Ey vz Re[Hz]) + 
   vy^2 Real[I Ey Conjugate[Hx]]))
```

So, I have the following replacement rule

```
{f_ x_ + f_ y_ -> f (x + y), f_ x_ - f_ y_ -> f (x - y)}
```

If I now do

```
3 Hx Re[Ez] vz - 3 Ez Re[Hx] vz //. {f_ x_ + f_ y_ -> f (x + y), f_ x_ - f_ y_ -> f (x - y)}
```

This gives me

```
(3 Hx Re[Ez] - 3 Ez Re[Hx]) vz
```

If I do the same on the above equation the rule just gives the same thing back to me. What I want is (I have manually manipulated this to give what I want to obtain as requested.)

```
-I (t2 - t4) (-vx vy Abs[Ex]^2) +
   vz^2 (Hx Re[Ey] - Ey Re[Hx]) + 
   vx vy (Hy Re[Ey] + Ex Re[Hx]) + 
   vy vz 3 (Hx Re[Ez] - Ez Re[Hx]) +
   (-vx^2 + vz^2) (Ex Re[Hy] - Hy Re[Ex])
   - vy vx Abs[Hy]^2
   - vy vz (Ex Re[Hz] + Hz Re[Ex])
   vx vz 3 (Hy Re[Ez] + Ez Re[Hy])
   + vx vz (Ey Re[Hz] - Hz Re[Ey]) + 
   vy^2 Real[I Ey Conjugate[Hx]]
```

My substitution rules are

```
 replrule1 = {f_ x_ + f_ y_ -> f (x + y), f_ x_ - f_ y_ -> f (x - y)}
 replrule2 = a_Complex x_ Re[y_] + b_Complex y_ Re[x_] :> 
   Abs[a] Real[I x Conjugate[y]] /; a == -b
 replrule4 = x_ Re[y_] - y_ Re[x_] -> Real[I x Conjugate[y]]
```

After that substitution I also want to apply

```
b_Complex y_ Re[x_] + a_Complex x_ Re[y_] :>  Abs[a] Real[I x Conjugate[y]] /; a == -b
```

Which has been a previous question of mine here.

Comment: Jonas, your edit confuses me a bit.  If you were originally using `//.` then I guess that is not producing the result you want.  Would you please include the exact output that you desire?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Done. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Jonas, pardon me if I am being slow, but I don't see `3 Hx Re[Ez] vz - 3 Ez Re[Hx] vz` in the output after doing the replacement.  Again I have to ask, what is the *compete* result that you are expecting?  I am asking you to manually manipulate that complete expression into the form that you desire.  I cannot otherwise understand what you expect to end up where.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Sorry about that. I have added some more. There is `3 Hx vz Re[Ez] - 3 Ez vz Re[Hx]` in the output which is to me the same but maybe Mathematica sees it differently internally.

Comment: I should still implement the DelayedRule. First I need to fully understand what is so different ;-).

Comment: I'm getting `... vz (3 Hx Re[Ez] - 3 Ez Re[Hx]) ...` in the output with ReplaceRepeated.

Comment: But it leaves the `3` untouched. With me the following certainly *does not* change: `vy (3 Hx Re[Ez] vz - 3 Ez Re[Hx] vz)`. It stays the same in the expression. I would also like to get the `3` outside.

Comment: Jonas, thank you, I will take a longer look at this tonight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In reply to the remaining issue addressed in the comments, here is the reason the 3 is not taken out of the brackets.

You have

```
rule = {f_ x_ + f_ y_ -> f (x + y), f_ x_ - f_ y_ -> f (x - y)};

3 Hx Re[Ez] vz - 3 Ez Re[Hx] vz //. rule
```

> vz (3 Hx Re[Ez] - 3 Ez Re[Hx])

leaving the multiple 3 inside.  Taking a simplified case, this works:

```
3 a + 3 b /. f_ x_ + f_ y_ :> f (x + y)
```

> 3 (a + b)

But this does not work, for the reason stated by Mr. Wizard:

```
3 a - 3 b /. f_ x_ - f_ y_ -> f (x - y)
```

> 3 a - 3 b

And neither does this:

```
3 a - 3 b /. f_ x_ + f_ y_ -> f (x + y)
```

> 3 a - 3 b

for reason that `FullForm[3 a - 3 b]` is

> Plus[Times[3, a], Times[-3, b]

so `f` cannot ever match `3` and `-3`.

An awkward solution to this simple case is:

```
3 a - 3 b /. 
 f_ x_ + g_ y_ :> 
  Which[f == g, f (x + y), f == -g, f (x - y), True, f x + g y]
```

> 3 (a - b)

But this does not work for more complicated inputs.

`Simplify` on the other hand works ok:

```
Simplify[3 a - 3 b]
```

> 3 (a - b)

```
3 Hx Re[Ez] vz - 3 Ez Re[Hx] vz // Simplify
```

> 3 vz (Hx Re[Ez] - Ez Re[Hx])

And perhaps `rule = f_ x_ + g_ y_ :> Simplify[f x + g y]` would work for your original case, depending on what you are specifically seeking.

Comment: I forgot to come back to this.  Good thing you remembered. (+1).

Answer (score 7):

Try [`ReplaceRepeated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceRepeated.html) (`//.`)

**On examination**

The rule is progressively implemented

```
rule = {f_ x_ + f_ y_ -> f (x + y), f_ x_ - f_ y_ -> f (x - y)}
```

on a sample selection

```
 (Hx vz^2 Re[Ey] - Ey vz^2 Re[Hx] + 
   vx (Hy vy Re[Ey] - Hz vz Re[Ey] + Ex vy Re[Hx]) + 
   vy (3 Hx vz Re[Ez] - 3 Ez vz Re[Hx])) /. rule
```

Output of which is further modified by `% /. rule` to a final form.

ReplaceRepeated goes straight to the final form:

```
 (Hx vz^2 Re[Ey] - Ey vz^2 Re[Hx] + 
   vx (Hy vy Re[Ey] - Hz vz Re[Ey] + Ex vy Re[Hx]) + 
   vy (3 Hx vz Re[Ez] - 3 Ez vz Re[Hx])) //. rule
```

**Simple Case**

ReplaceAll matches one match:

```
a + b + c /. x_ + y_ -> x y
```

a (b + c)

ReplaceRepeated matches all occurrences

```
a + b + c //. x_ + y_ -> x y
```

a b c

Comment: I actually have used ReplaceRepeated but it does not change the output.

Comment: It changes your original expression when I try it.  ReplaceAll takes five interations to arrive at the final form that ReplaceRepeated produces in a single evaluation.

Answer (score 5):

I still believe this kind of transformation is often misguided.  Nevertheless, here are some tips.

You should usually use [`RuleDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RuleDelayed.html) (`:>`) when using named patterns:

```
rule = {f_ x_ + f_ y_ :> f (x + y)};
```

*Mathematica* represents `a - b` as `a + (-1 b)`, therefore:

```
{f x + f y, f x - f y - f z, f x - f y + f z} //. rule
```

> ```
> {f (x + y), f (x - y - z), f (x - y + z)}
> ```

Comment: Two questions: 1. why are these kinds of transformations misguided? And, 2. why should you use `RuleDelayed` with named patterns, it seems to work with just `Rule`? The second question isn't meant to be facetious, it is more about why use the one, when the other obviously works. And, when do you use named patterns with `Rule`.

Comment: @rcollyer I suppose that you are asking on the OP's behalf. (1) as has been stated elsewhere using replacement rules for mathematical operations is often, but by no means always, problematic, and often, but by no means always, better done differently. (2) RuleDelayed is a matter of good habit; in this case the symbols are undefined and it doesn't matter, but the habit of using `{ h[x_] -> x }` is a pitfall because you are mixing the local and global meanings of `x`.

Comment: For the first question, yes I was. For the second, I wasn't coming up with an example where it would have problems, so I asked.